# Detect when Flash Player throttle starts / end

Tags: browser, cross-browser, flash

In FP 10.1 Adobe introduced throttling. (see below).

Have anyone found a good way of detecting when this starts / stops?

I know Adobe has plan of making an event for this later on, but it's not even included in the upcomming FP 11 release.

---

*Throttling:
Non-visible SWFs and SWFs on hidden tabs are throttled down to 2 frames per second. No rendering occurs unless the SWF becomes visible again. Timers and local connections are also clocked down to 2 FPS. Video is decoded but not rendered or displayed using idle CPU time while audio plays back at 8 FPS to preserve backwards compatibility.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Flash Player 11.2 this is now possible using `ThrottleEvent`

See documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/ThrottleEvent.html